# How to fill combobox in a Visual Studio C++ Win32 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, combobox

How can I fill a combobox in a Visual Studio C++ Win32 project. And how can check that which word was selected by the user.

I mean I want a comboxbox for example filled with these: One, Two, Three. And I want to do different events depends on which one was chosen by the user.

Edit: The windows was created as a dialogbox in the resource editor and the message thread runs like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, DlgProc);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is all spelled out pretty clearly in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775792.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the WM_INITDIALOG handler for the dialog, you can initialize the combo box with the strings you wish to select with the [CB_ADDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775828.aspx) message:

```
SendMessage(hCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) L"one");
```

Now you can respond to the [CBN_SELENDOK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775825.aspx) message to respond to user changes to the dropdown.